# How to minimize code duplication in sql query?

Tags: php, sql

I am working on the SQL query code in which I want to avoid the sql query duplication.

**Below is the sql query code:**

```
    switch ($y) {
        case 'l.text':
            $query->order('numeric_text ' . (strtolower($x) == 'DESC' ? 'DESC' : 'ASC') .
                ', ' . $y . ' ' . (strtolower($x) == 'DESC' ? 'DESC' : 'ASC'));
            break;
    }
```

In the above SQL Query code `strtolower($x) == 'DESC' ? 'DESC' : 'ASC'` is being used at two places. I am thinking to place a varibale there instead.

**This is what I have tried:**

```
    $sortOrder = (strtolower($x) == 'DESC' ? 'DESC' : 'ASC');

    switch ($y) {
        case 'l.text':
            $query->order('numeric_text ' . $sortOrder . ', ' . $y . ' ' . $sortOrder);
            break;
    }
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering if there is any other better way, we can avoid sql query duplication.

Comment: What you are doing now looks OK to me.  One slight optimization might take advantage of that `ASC` order is the default sort if neither `ASC` or `DESC` is specified.  So, you could use: `$sortOrder = (strtolower($x) == 'DESC' ? 'DESC' : '')`

Comment: I've got to say that `strtolower($x)` will **never** equal `'DESC'`. Perhaps you want `strtoupper($x)`? Also, if `strtoupper($x)` can only ever take values of `'ASC'` or `'DESC'`, you can just use `$x` directly in the query as SQL doesn't care about the case.

Comment: If $x isn't 'DESC', what else can it be? :)

Comment: @John is this only portion that you want to condense?  Like Tim, I feel this is already using variables appropriately to write DRY code. I generally try to avoid verbose switch blocks, but they have their time and place.  I think you may be overthinking this.  Do you have a lot of cases in your switch block? Is that the greater concern in terms of duplication?  Have you rolled your own db query query methods or are you using a well-known framework?

Comment: You should probably provide a little more information. like, how many cases are there? How big is the destinction between different cases? How much code duplication do you have? Are there instances of code duplication other than the one with the sortOrder?
Those are all questions that should be answered if you want to have the best possible answer on to how you can optimize your code.
I mean, what you did with the sort order is right so far, but it seems to me there is more behind your question. Otherwise you would just have gone with the answer you provided yourself.

Comment: Bounty? really ? for this problem!, it is not even a problem. It is more like a coding style preference. John, what you did is Perfect, don't waste your time man, you still have millions of lines of code waiting for you to write.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use a function in your model or in helper library to do that job for you, and use it around your project, it could be a good idea to DRY your code.

```
// Helper

function sort_statment($fields, $sort_order) {
  $sort_statment = '';
  foreach($fields as $field){
     $sort_statment += $field . ' ' . $sort_order 
  }
  return $sort_statment;
}


// Model 
$sort_fields ['numeric_text', 'other_field', $y ....];

switch ($y) {
    case 'l.text':
        $query->order(sort_statment($sort_fields, $sort_order);
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like Nick mentionned in the comments, you can't lower a string and have it equal to 'DESC' or 'ASC', assuming it's just a typo you can just overwrite your variable instead of declaring a new one :

```
    if(strtoupper($x) != 'DESC') $x = 'ASC';

switch ($y) {
    case 'l.text':
        $query->order('numeric_text ' . strtoupper($x) . ', ' . $y . ' ' . strtoupper($x));
        break;
}
```

It would also help to know what values $x can take.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to minimize code duplication you can separate code by three parts: determination of sort order, determination of column name and making of a query. For example:

```
// determination of sort order
$sortOrder = (strtoupper($x) == 'DESC' ? 'DESC' : 'ASC');


// determination of column name
switch ($y) {
    case 'l.text':           
        $column = 'numeric_text';
        break;
}

// making of a query
$query->order($column . $sortOrder . ', ' . $y . ' ' . $sortOrder);
```

Of course, you can create functions or methods (if you use OOP) with those parts of the code. For example:

```
/**
 * determination of sort order
 */
function getSortOrder($x)
{
    return strtoupper($x) == 'DESC' ? 'DESC' : 'ASC';
}

/**
 * determination of column name
 */
function getColumn($y)
{
    switch ($y) {
        case 'l.text':           
            return 'numeric_text';
            break;
    }
}

/**
 * making of a query
 */
function addOrder($query, $x, $y) 
{
    $sortOrder = getSortOrder($x);
    $column = getColumn(y);
    $query->order($column . $sortOrder . ', ' . $y . ' ' . $sortOrder);
}
```

Also, if you have many columns, you can use mapping instead of `case` statement. It will make your code more comfortable to read. For example:

```
// determination of column name
$map = [
   'l.text' => 'numeric_text'
];
$column = key_exists($y, $map) ? $map[$y] : 'default_column'
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use shorthand of ternary operator shorthand

```
<?php
$sortOrder = $sortOrder ?: 'ASC';

switch ($y) {
    case 'l.text':
        $query->order("numeric_text {$sortOrder},{$y} {$sortOrder}");
        break;
}
```

Comment: Because that would be the same thing as not checking `$sortOrder` at all (except for the edge case where it is falsey or undefined).
(Granted that the original code is *wrong* and equals always setting the sort order to ASC...)